# Unhandled exception at 0x00af7230 in CPP_TEST.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00abcdef

Tags: c++, c, linux-kernel, operating-system, interrupt

I am getting `Access violation writing location at 0xABCDEF`.
I have tried many ways to solve this. But finally could not able to do it.

```
#define xyz 0xABCDEF
#define ptr (UINT16 *) (xyz)

int main()
{

    //int *ptr;
    //ptr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *ptr = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev: I want fill zero at that particular location.

Comment: Not every location is a "legal" location. Reading or writing from an arbitrary location without having a referencing variable is technically undefined behaviour.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev: It is a configuration resister address. I need to disable the interrupt there

Comment: If you're running inside an OS, the OS should provide a way to do that -- and block you from doing it yourself.  Its whole job is to serve as a referee between processes; it takes control of the hardware and memory so processes don't go trampling all over each other.  You'd only need to mess with the hardware directly if you're writing a kernel driver...at which point you should already have some knowledge of how the OS's protection mechanisms work.

Comment: What OS do you use? How can you be sure that this particular memory location is belong to your process?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dereference arbitrary memory location in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270797/dereference-arbitrary-memory-location-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it, because the memory location you trying to use is not belong to your process. Your program literally don't have proper permissions to do that.

This is not a good practice trying to manually guess and define the memory address, because using of such addresses basically causes undefined behavior situation.

Actually, that address `0xABCDEF` you trying to use looks like it was taken from some kind of tutorial as an example. Probably, you would replace it with actual address that is specific for your system and OS configuration?

Comment: Not only he doesn't have rights, it is undefined behaviour even if it didn't segfault. That piece of memory could hold some other part of the program/data as well.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev: Technically it is.  But that kind of "UB" is pretty standard and even necessary in some cases, like when you're writing an OS in C.  Something tells me that's not the case here, though...  :)

Comment: @cHao: Yes you are right.

Comment: @MikhailKalashnikov: I think you are right... Instead of scraching my head with an ananymous address, I should go ahead with specific address

Answer (score 1):

You don't have permissions to fill with zero a location that doesn't belong to your process.

If you want to fill with zero at a particular location you have to allocate that memory 1st... you have to delete your line "#define ptr..." and do something like in your commented code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int* ptr = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
    *ptr = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: :- I need to fill zero in that particular location

Comment: why? why is that location special for you?

Comment: :- The above code is an example or a small part of my project, actually I need to disable an interrupt, which happens at that location.

Answer (score 1):

Your program will be given only a certain amount of memory by the operating system.
You can request additional memory using malloc() , then you will get a contiguous chunk of memory from the heap , again this allocation is done by operating system.

Remember these points,

> Your program cannot specify the memory address at which you want your memory to be allocated.
>
> Your program cannot access any random memory address , since it will be monitored by virtual memory manager , and any violation will  raise an hardware exception.
>
> There is certainly no logic in wanting your memory to be allocated at one particular address.

Comment: Although it's good advice in general, it's overstating just a bit.  There *is* logic in wanting to use a specific address, in some cases; memory-mapped I/O and particularly video buffers spring to mind as examples.  Just happens that any self-respecting OS for x86 won't let you do that without talking to it first.

Comment: @cHao , Yes i am aware there are benefits in using only certain section of memory , for example out of LOW_MEM,HIGH_MEM,DMA , for performance critical applications , i would choose LOW_MEM , because the virtual addresses are mapped directly to the logical adresses , bypassing the virtual memory manager , hence reducing the latency of     VMM allocating memory using demand paging and setting up the page flags. But still no where i have come across , where you have the ability to exactly select a page address , apart in the cases where there is a firmware involved.